# C-c C-x f (org-footnote-action) cannot create a new footnote

Tags: org-mode

I am used to create new footnotes in Emacs Org Mode with the key binding C-c C-x f.

But now there are shown several options in the echo area, when I use this key binding, although the cursor is not on a footnote reference or definition. and I did not use a prefix argument.
And I didn't change any variables or configurations (intentional).

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the docstring of `org-footnote-action` (emphasis mine):

> (org-footnote-action &optional SPECIAL)
>
> Do the right thing for footnotes.
>
> When at a footnote reference, jump to the definition.
>
> When at a definition, jump to the references if they exist, offer
>   to create them otherwise.
>
> When neither at definition or reference, create a new footnote,
>   interactively if possible.
>
> With prefix arg SPECIAL, or **when no footnote can be created**,
>   offer additional commands in a menu.

So it seems that when point is at beginning of line it is considered no footnote can be created.  Arguably, this could be made more explicit.

I actually wonder if it's a bug: the test is performed by function `org-footnote--allow-reference-p`, where one can read on the source (for org-version 9.1.14):

```el
(defun org-footnote--allow-reference-p ()
  "Non-nil when a footnote reference can be inserted at point."
  ;; XXX: This is similar to `org-footnote-in-valid-context-p' but
  ;; more accurate and usually faster, except in some corner cases.
  ;; It may replace it after doing proper benchmarks as it would be
  ;; used in fontification.
  (unless (bolp)
         ...
```

As we can see, the beginning of line test is the very first one.  Also, it turns out that the mentionned `org-footnode-in-valid-context-p` function does return `t` when point is at beginning of line.

Answer (score 0):

By chance I found my mistake:
The cursor was at the beginning of a line.

But I don't understand exactly what's the problem. Perhaps it is in conjunction with the variable org-footnote-define-inline, which defines where the footnote appears.